# Why does my fillText don't show / disappear on the canvas although it should be?

Tags: javascript, canvas

**Context**

I have a function that draws a canvas based on the data passed to it.
Here is the function:

```
import { mapColorsToNumbers } from "./mapColorToNumber";

export const drawGame = (pixelArt, ctx) => {
  const rectCount = JSON.parse(pixelArt.pixels).length;

  
  const canvasPixelsCount =
    pixelArt.pixelArtWidth * pixelArt.pixelArtHeight - 1000;

  
  const newRectSize = Math.sqrt(canvasPixelsCount / rectCount);

  const colorsWithCodes = mapColorsToNumbers(JSON.parse(pixelArt.pixels));
  

  JSON.parse(pixelArt.pixels).forEach((pixel) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeRect(
      pixel.x * newRectSize,
      pixel.y * newRectSize,
      newRectSize,
      newRectSize
    );
    // drawColorCode(ctx, pixel, newRectSize, colorsWithCodes);
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.font = "18px serif";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    const textX = pixel.x * newRectSize + newRectSize / 2;

    // if I set this line to "+" instead of "-" everything is gone. When  I set it to "-" everything is one "rect" above it should be so "+" should do the trick
    // instead everything dissapears
    const textY = pixel.y * newRectSize + newRectSize / 2;

    // this does not work. 
    ctx.fillText("1", textX, textY);
    console.log(
      `pixel x ${textX} (index: ${pixel.x}) vs pixel y ${textY} (index: ${pixel.y})`
    );
    
    // This does work and the coordinates are even in the array
    // ctx.fillText("1", 585, 585);

    if (pixel.pickedColor !== "white") {
      ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
      ctx.fillRect(
        pixel.x * newRectSize,
        pixel.y * newRectSize,
        newRectSize,
        newRectSize
      );
    } else {
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.fillRect(
        pixel.x * newRectSize,
        pixel.y * newRectSize,
        newRectSize,
        newRectSize
      );
    }
  });
};
```

**The Problem:**

The drawing function works. It draws a grid of pixels with all pixels colored shown.
BUT:

The problem is in these lines of code:

```
const textX = pixel.x * newRectSize + newRectSize / 2;

    // if I set this line to "+" instead of "-" everything is gone. When  I set it to "-" everything is one "rect" above it should be so "+" should do the trick
    // instead everything dissapears
    const textY = pixel.y * newRectSize + newRectSize / 2;

    // this does not work. 
    ctx.fillText("1", textX, textY);
```

So you can read in the comment what a weird problem that is. When I write:

`const textY = pixel.y * newRectSize - newRectSize / 2;`

It looks like that:

[image]

When I write it the correct way `const textY = pixel.y * newRectSize + newRectSize / 2;`
, so it pushes it one "rect" down, every single number is gone. The drawing itself still looks good but gone are all the numbers.

When I write a longer Text like so:

`ctx.fillText("Hello", textX, textY);`
It looks like that:

[image]

I really don't get why that is. I looked at the data array and painted a few texts manually from the data  and with that everything looks good. But when drawn with the formula itself it doesn't work.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: You are calling fillRect() over that spot right after, your text will be covered by that rectangle. BTW, you would be better drawing the grid in two calls (one for the gray area and one for the strokes, after you cleared the canvas with white).

Comment: Thats it my man. Thx. If you want you can answer this question and I will approve it.

Comment: There is very little chance that someone facing this same issue finds this q/a, so I won't answer it and prefer to see it closed.